# Lua. Быстрый перебор элементов таблицы с использованием многопоточности

Tags: lua

Имеется некая таблица, которая перебирается следующим образом:

```
for i = #someTable, 1, -1 do 
    -- итераторы не используются для большей производительности
    local t = someTable[i]
    func1(t.a, t.b)
    func2(t.c)
    if t.foobar then t.foobar() end
    func3(t)
end
```

Хотелось бы ускорить данный процесс с использованием корутин (перебирать в несколько потоков). Как организовать данный процесс на Lua без сторонних библиотек? И есть ли ещё какие способы ускорить перебор?

Comment: Сопрограммы (сoroutine) не потоки. Они выполняются в одном и том же потоке, просто дают возможность прервать выполнение кода в одной функции (сопрограмме) и переключиться в другую функцию. А потом вернуться назад, в ту же точку. Так что на сопрограммах никакого ускорения вы не получите.

Comment: А можно ли вообще тогда как-нибудь ускорить этот процесс?

Comment: Можно оптимизировать алгоритм - проходить каждую итерацию быстрее, или пропускать ненужные итерации. Что конкретно выделаете с каждым элементом?

Comment: Элементы - таблицы. Из него берутся несколько полей и с ними работа ведётся отдельно. В случае, если элемент имеет функцию, то она выполняется. Затем элемент в любом случае передаётся следующей функции, на этом итерация заканчивается

Comment: @zed мне известно это, но в книге Р. Иерузалимски написано, что, в случае многопроцессорной машины, корутины работают параллельно основному потоку

Comment: @Vidoom можно номер страницы/ссылку где вы это прочитали?

Comment: @zed Глава 9 "Сопрограммы", прямо в введении этой главы. "Основное отличие между нитями и сопрограммам - это то, что концептуально (или буквально, в случае многопроцессорной машины) программа с нитями выполняет несколько нитей параллельно." Прямую ссылку дать не могу, но это действительно отрывок из главы

Comment: @Vidoom ну так в этой цитате как раз и написано, что нити выполняются параллельно, а не сопрограммы. Вообще, Lua машина написана на ANSI C (С89) и использует только возможности стандартной библиотеки, в которой такого понятия как поток/нить нету. Соответственно, из коробки, в Lua и нету возможностей для многопоточного программирования и работы с потоками. Это решается только через сторонние библиотеки.

Comment: @zed теперь всё понял, спасибо большое